# Value of checkbox not set in edit form of jqGrid when using editoptions

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I noticed that if I set an `editoptions` parameter to a column with `edittype:'checkbox'`, the value of the checkbox is not being set in the edit form.

You can reproduce it even with an empty object as editoptions.

```
...
colModel: [
    {name: 'checked', index: 'checked', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox', editoptions:{}}
]
...
```

Try to select the first row and edit it in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sceb/57/)

It appears to be a bug in jqgrid, but I haven't found any fix or workaround. Does anyone know one?

In my specific situation, I am using the editoptions to populate `dataEvents` for the input element, so I cannot remove it.

Comment: Your demo uses very very old (6 years old) version 4.1.2 of jqGrid. The version is dead since a long time. I strictly recommend you to upgrade to the current version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) - free jqGrid 4.14.0. One need to use in the case at least jQuery 1.7.2, but it's recommended to use jQuery 3.2.1 or 1.12.4 if you need support of old web browsers. I recommend you to look through [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html).

Comment: @Oleg, Thank you, it seems its working in the current version. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo uses very very old (6 years old) version 4.1.2 of jqGrid. The version is dead since a long time. I strictly recommend you to upgrade to the current version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) - free jqGrid 4.14.0. It's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop since the end of 2014. Free jqGrid require to use at least jQuery 1.7.2, but it's recommended to use jQuery 3.2.1 or 1.12.4 if you need support of old web browsers.

I recommend you additionally to look through [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) some base new features existing in free jqGrid fork. For example, one can use Font Awesome icons to improve the visibility of the grid. Additional information can be found in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and in READMEs of previously published versions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part ", editoptions:{}"

Use this instead:
colModel: [
    {name: 'checked', index: 'checked', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox'}
]

Comment: I set the editoptions to an empty object in the demo for simplicity. In reality I have the editoptions populated with dataEvents, so I cannot remove it.

Comment: then you need to add your values inside editoptions object like this:
editoptions:{id: "2", checked: "false", checked2: "true"}